# Responsive: tabs to accordion

Tags: html, css, accordion

I found this code [DEMO](https://codepen.io/cancher/pen/teHpE)

Much helpful. On responsive mode the tabs become accordion, but the problem is the accordion is not closable until we click on another accordion tab. What I'm trying to achieve is it should work as a perfect accordion. When clicking open and click again to close. I saw another solutions in Stack, but it doesn't work the way I described. Can anyone help?

```js
// tabbed content
// http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");

});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});


/* Extra class "tab_last" 
   to add border to right side
   of last tab */
$('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 11px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 31px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_last {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 -->
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an if statement to check if the targeted one has an active class and if the statement evaluate to true just hide it the following is an example where all are on hide

```js
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == 'active' || $(this).attr("class") == 'tab_last active') {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + activeTab).fadeOut();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").removeClass("d_active");
  } else {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");
  }
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});


/* Extra class "tab_last" 
   to add border to right side
   of last tab */
$('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 11px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 31px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_last {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 -->
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

If you don't all to start on hide you can simply set the first tab on show like the following

```js
// tabbed content
// http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

/* if in tab mode */
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  if ($(this).attr("class") == 'active' || $(this).attr("class") == 'tab_last active') {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + activeTab).fadeOut();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").removeClass("d_active");
  } else {
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
    $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

    $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
    $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='" + activeTab + "']").addClass("d_active");
  }
});
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
  $("ul.tabs li[rel^='" + d_activeTab + "']").addClass("active");
});


/* Extra class "tab_last" 
   to add border to right side
   of last tab */
$('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
ul.tabs {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 11px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 31px;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-left: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_last {
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
}

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li rel="tab1" class="active">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>
</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 -->
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Actually what I was expecting is when on mobile mode, the tabs become accordions. So when I click on an accordion it should close and another click on the same accordion it should open. You know like a simple accordion. For some reason my codes are all not working